# image blocking interaction to buttons

Tags: android-layout

I can't post images yet so if you [look here](http://cl.ly/image/3i2S2K3m351D) you can see my menu and the shadow from the content on the right is mostly alpha channel that is covering my menu items. This is catching all the interaction that I want to go to the menu buttons. How can I fix this while still having the shadow?

I have already tried these different functions of the View class:

- `.setAlpha(0);`
- `.setEnabled(false);`
- `.setClickable(false);`
- `.setEnabled(false);`
- `.setFocusable(false);`

All to no avail. With `.setVisibility(GONE)` the buttons work, but there is no shadow.  So I need a way to keep the shadow and allow clicks through.